# google.maps.LatLng is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

all.  I am building a web app with a google map.  All was working fine until I decided to add the autocomplete feature to the address box.  My original JavaScript include was:

Everything was working fine.  Once I added the autocomplete feature, I saw that I had to change the JavaScript include to:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?signed_in=true&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete" async defer></script>
```

The autocomplete works, but the older map code is now broken.  Specifically, I get this error:

> TypeError: google.maps.LatLng is not a function

I get it everywhere I have the following code:

```
var googlePosition = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
```

From my tests, I can tell it has something to do with the portion after the JavaScript include.

```
signed_in=true&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete async defer
```

Any ideas as to how I can get both of these features working together?

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, get rid off the **async defer** attributes.

Then have a look at this:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script

> **async**
>   Set this Boolean attribute to indicate that the browser
>   should, if possible, execute the script asynchronously. It has no
>   effect on inline scripts (i.e., scripts that don't have the src
>   attribute).
>
> **defer**
>   This Boolean attribute is set to indicate to a browser that the script
>   is meant to be executed after the document has been parsed. Since this
>   feature hasn't yet been implemented by all other major browsers,
>   authors should not assume that the script’s execution will actually be
>   deferred. The defer attribute shouldn't be used on scripts that don't
>   have the src attribute. Since Gecko 1.9.2, the defer attribute is
>   ignored on scripts that don't have the src attribute. However, in
>   Gecko 1.9.1 even inline scripts are deferred if the defer attribute is
>   set.

Comment: Thanks a bunch!  I had tried removing async defer with no luck.  I then tried various combinations of parameters and finally found one that worked.  This is what I ended up with:

  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>

Thanks again!